# Is there a way to make sIFR font-weight as font?

Tags: css, sifr

I have a little problem. I want to use Helvetica Neue 75 Bold in sIFR, but I can’t manage to make a working sifr-file. It works perfectly with Helvetica Neue Ultra Light, and Black, but not Bold. I guess it is because bold is an option in css, and so on, but I’ve tried that. I also tried to convert it to ttf, and then export it via [sIFR Generator](http://www.sifrgenerator.com/wizard.html). but then the font got a cut in the top. I tried several times, and several fonts, and it happend on all. It never happens when I make the sifr-file from flash.

I’ve also tried Coffeecup sIFR Font Maker, but because they haven’t updated they’re programme (it doesn’t support the r436), i don’t want to use that either.

any solution?

is there a way to make Helvetica Neue 75 Bold as a “normal” font and not as a font-weight?

edit: I fixed the file from sIFR Generator with offsetTop method in the sifr-config.js (:

Comment: Given your edit, is this still an issue? If not, could you add your solution as a comment and accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the tuneHeight and offsetTop parameters in sifr-config.js to fix this problem! (:
( http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods )

**tuneHeight (Number)**:
Positive or negative number which is added to the height of the Flash movie. This allows for tuning of the space surrounding the text.

**offsetTop (Number)**:
Positive or negative number which specifies the vertical position of the text inside the Flash movie.